# checking the correctness of a sequential calculus

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

For reference I am studying via Mathematical Logic by Ebbinghaus, and am operating under the following definition of correctness:
a sequent $\Gamma\phi$ is called correct if $\Gamma\models\phi$ (where $\Gamma$ is some other sequent)

Okay, now the question: Decide whether the following rule is correct. 
$\frac{\phi \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \psi}{\exists x\phi \ \ \ \ \exists x\psi}$ 
I have come to the conclusion that it is correct via the following logic. Please tell me if my logic is incorrect, and also, if I profusely over complicated this question. 
I broke the question down into four cases 
(i) $x \in $ free$(\phi)$ $x \in $ free$(\psi)$ 
(ii) $x \notin $ free$(\phi)$ $x \notin $ free$(\psi)$ 
(iii) $x \notin $ free$(\phi)$ $x \in $ free$(\psi)$ 
(iv) $x \in $ free$(\phi)$ $x \notin $ free$(\psi)$

As for (i) it trivially holds as the witness for the result of the calculus can be the same in both the succeedant and antecedant
(ii) holds trivially as in this case the corresponding antecedants and succedants are logically equivalent. 
(iii) In this case however, any thing can serve as the witness for the succeedant of the result of the calculus, as anything that models $\phi$ models $\psi$, and $\phi$ does not contain $x$ free, meaning the assignment of $x$ can vary, meaning $x$ can be anything 
And in the case of (iv), $\psi$ is not dependant on the assignment of $x$, just of it's existence, as whenever $\phi$ is true, $\psi$ is true despite not having $x$ free, meaning that whenever $\exists x \phi$ is true $\psi$ is true by the fact that the witness of $\exists x\phi$ exists.

All four cases being true means the rule must be correct. (my explanation of (iv) is what is throwing me off) Thanks for any help.

Comment: I really don't understand your notation
"ϕ       ψ / ∃xϕ    ∃xψ"
could you clarify a bit?

Comment: @Julián Everything besides the last formula is the antecedant, and the last formula is the succedant. This calculus takes the sequent where phi is the antecedant and psi is the succedant, and yields the calculus where exists phi is the antecedant and exists psi is the succedant

Comment: @Julián the $\vdash$ sign is omitted. The upper sequents reads: $\phi \vdash \psi$. And so the lower one.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ah! Ok, thanks. Are you asking then just if that rule is derivable syntactically? If so, are you familiar with the system LK? If not, it's ok.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No I am asked whether these rules are "correct" (when given correct premises would this calculus yield correct results) Where should I read about the system LK? Not sure I've heard of it but maybe it's the system my book is introducing me to without a name

Comment: But there is also an indirect way to prove it: to show that the lower sequent is derivable from the upper one and then use the soundness of the proof system.